# "getElementById returns undefined" when accessing asp:HiddenField in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have MasterPage/ContentPage, where in `ContentPage.aspx` file i have `java-script` code. I want to move the java-script code out of `ContentPage.aspx` to a separate js file and do the following:

//in ContentPage.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/file1.js") %>'></script>
```

In file1.js i copy and paste all java-script code. On the java-script code, i have a cide line:

//file1.js:

```
var hiddenvar1 = document.getElementById('<%=hiddenvariable1.ClientID%>');
```

..then and i cannot get the value of that variable (hiddenvar1.value) because object hiddenvar1 is null. The javascript code was working when it was inside ContentPage.aspx. When i moved it to file1.js it's not working anymore.

Comment: Do this stuff "after DOM load" (search for what this means). For an initial load or *normal* postback it would suffice to put the script "at the very bottom of the body element" (search for the debate of onload/foot-scripts). It *should* work at the very bottom of the ASPX page as well. The thing that changed is the *order of execution* of the JavaScript and DOM creation.

Comment: Search SO for "getElementById undefined".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use asp:HiddenField value in javascript on page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442968/use-asphiddenfield-value-in-javascript-on-page-load) (read the answer carefully)

Comment: @pst, this does not seems duplicate post. OP is asking to access Hidden Field in separate JavaScript file.

Comment: @Guest exactly the same thing but store in a file.

Comment: @gillesc - Yes, We are at same track.

Answer (score 0):

`Page Load` Code.

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), 
Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"), "MyjavaScriptFunction('" + 
MyHiddenField.ClientID + "');", true);
```

---

### JavaScript

```
function abc(ObjID){
    var Val = document.getElementById(ObjID).value;
    alert(Val);
}
```